# odd even using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

My homework is to return whether the given number is odd or even (Boolean value), using recursive functions: `true` for even and `false` for odd. I have ended up with two similar functions.

My problem is that one function always returns `true`, and other always returns `false`.

The code below gives `true` for any number

```
function t(n){
    if (n=2){
      return true;
    }
    else if (n=1){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return n-t(n-2);
    }
}


console.log(t(3));
// true
```

The code below gives `false` for any number

```
function t(n){
    if (n=0){
      return true;
    }
    else if (n=1){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return n-t(n-2);
    }
}


console.log(t(3));
// false
```

Comment: `=` is not for comparing ...

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @CarlosFranco Because his teacher asked him to write it, of course.

Comment: @Teemu i am assigning n to those,There is no comparing here

Comment: @user7428900 You don't want to be assigning. `if (n=0){` should be `if (n===0){`. You're trying to *check* the value of `n`, no?

Comment: Hmm... Why the `if`s then? `n=0` gives always falsy, `n=1` gives always truthy in `if`.

Comment: `if (n=2){ return true; }` will always return true.  As you point out, there is no comparing here, you assign 2 to n and then return true because the result is non zero.

Comment: i got it!.Thanks @Teemu and everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems in your code are

- You test an assignment, `n=1`.  The comparison operation would be `n == 1`.
- Your recursion case makes an invalid operation:

  return n-t(n-2)

`n` is an integer; the return value of `t` is Boolean (supposedly).  For the simple case of n=4, what do you intend to return?  You recur with the call `t(2)`.  This returns `true`, so your previous call now evaluates `4-true` and returns that value.  This is unlikely to be what you want.

Fix the `if` conditions.  Change the recursive call to merely `t(n-2)`.
If you run into further trouble, try inserting a few strategically-place `print` statements to trace the execution path and one or two significant values.

Answer (score 3):

The general approach for this would be to deduct `2` from your value on each recursion level.

This way, the recursion base case would be such that if:

a) we reach `0`, number is even

b) we reach `1`, number is odd.

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
evenOrOdd(number) {
  if number equals 0
    return 'even'
  if number equals 1
    return 'odd'
  return evenOrOdd(number - 2);
}
```

Note: this only works for positive numbers. For negative number you'd do addition instead of subtraction.

Comment: I was gonna say...this'll bomb if `number` is negative :-)

Comment: The idea is to point the OP in the right direction, not clearly solve their HW :)

Comment: If you compare with the rest of the division, resolve the negative number issue

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the assignment equal sign in the if condition with the comparison equal sign. And if your function returns a boolean value you can't subtract the n variable with the result of the function because they are respectively an Integer and a Boolean value. I hope that I lend you an hand.